# Vector Space Operation

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that given any vector space $V$ over any field $F$ we have $(\alpha-\beta)(x-y)=\alpha x-\alpha y-\beta x+\beta y$ for all $x,y \in V$ and $\alpha,\beta \in F$?

I figured that, for example, if, say, $a$ and $b$ are contained in a field $F$, which—by definition—is a commutative associative ring, which, similarly, is—by definition—an additive abelian group, then the equation
\begin{eqnarray}
x+a & = & b
\end{eqnarray}
has a unique solution. This is because if we consider $s$ a solution to the above equation—that is, $s+a=b$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
(s+a)+(-a) & = & b+(-a),
\end{eqnarray}
so
\begin{eqnarray}
(s+a)+(-a) & = & s+(a+(-a)) 
& = & s+0
& = & s,
\end{eqnarray}
thus
\begin{eqnarray}
s & = & b+(-a).
\end{eqnarray}

This being the case—that is, this uniqueness, then

\begin{eqnarray}
(\alpha-\beta)= \alpha+(-\beta)
\end{eqnarray}

should be a unique scalar in $F$, so by the multiplicative distributivity of vectors in a vector space shouldn't the proposed operation hold for all vector spaces of and arbitrary non-single-element field? I don't even know if my thoughts are in the right place really. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about $GF(2)$?

Comment: Vinberg says that "[a] ring that consists of only zero is not regarded as a field," but what about non-zero single-element rings? Is that even possible?

Comment: No. A ring, by definition, has a zero element; if the ring has only one element, it's got to be zero.

Comment: @Trancot You can [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/354617/edit) your question, no need to leave the above remarks as comments.

Comment: @ZevChonoles How should I approach proving this?

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes. [Wikipedia's entry on modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29#Formal_definition) says this explicitly among the module axioms in the formal definition. A vector space is a module over a field.